# Woocommerce webhook not showing response

Tags: php, laravel, api, woocommerce

I am working on a webhook to notice when an order gets updated.

My webhook function looks like this:

```
public function webhook(Request $request) {

    if(!empty(Request::header('x-wc-webhook-delivery-id'))) {

        $head = Request::header('x-wc-webhook-source');
        $site = preg_replace('{/$}', '', $head);

        $webhookId = Request::header('x-wc-webhook-id');
        $deliveryId = Request::header('x-wc-webhook-delivery-id');

        $this->webhookOrders($site, $webhookId, $deliveryId);
    }

}
```

So it will fire the webhookOrders function which is only getting the updated order by WebhookId & deliveryId:

```
 $delivery = $woocommerce->get('webhooks/'.$webhookId.'/deliveries/'.$deliveryId);
```

Although the strange part is that when I try to access this get request through the webhook it is showing me an empty response:

```
    Array
(
    [id] => 559
    [duration] => 
    [summary] => 
    [request_method] => 
    [request_url] => https://<my_platform>/api/v1/orders/create
    [request_headers] => 
    [request_body] => 
    [response_code] => 
    [response_message] => 
    [response_headers] => 
    [response_body] => 
    [date_created] => 2018-02-28T10:48:05
    [_links] => Array
        (
            [self] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => https://<my_woo_site>/wp-json/wc/v1/webhooks/0/deliveries/559
                        )

                )

            [collection] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => https://<my_woo_site>/wp-json/wc/v1/webhooks/0/deliveries
                        )

                )

            [up] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [href] => https://<my_woo_site>/wp-json/wc/v1/webhooks/0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

While in the Woocommerce admin panel it is showing me that there is content:

[image]

Also, the thing what's driving me crazy is that when I access the URL outside the webhook it is showing me the content. And the log files are not showing any error.

Hope someone knows the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

deliveries are not logged any more.

> @deprecated 3.3.0 Webhooks deliveries logs now uses logging system.